# "an off track door"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, adjectives, noun-phrases

To describe a sliding door or bifold door coming off its track, I would say

> The door has come off the track.

But it seems increasingly popular to omit the definite article and just say

> The door has come off track.

Is that a fair observation? This also apparently applies to

> The door was off the track.

vs.

> The door was off track.

But neither seem to have more than a handful attestations on Google Books. Are there better ways to say this? Also how do you describe a door that has come off the track? Because either with or without the definite article the following phrase only yields exactly two hits on Google Books.

> An off-(the)-track door

Answer (score 1):

The door has come off **its** track.

It is now an **off-track door.**

They **race off track**.
They're  **off-track racers.**

The door **came off its hinges**. It is now **an unhinged door**.

But be careful there because if a person is unhinged, they're nuts.

The train came **off its or the rails (or tracks)**.

It is now a **derailed train**.

**There is no hard-and-fast rule for this stuff.**

Those remarks are off topic. They are off-topic remarks.

Bear in mind that with sliding doors, it is the rollers(wheels) that come out of their tracks.

Here is an example with a sliding door on a track, in a bathroom:

If an off-track roller isn’t the problem, you’ll have to remove the doors to adjust and possibly replace the rollers. Many doors have a small plastic guide at the middle of the lower rail. To remove this type of guide, just remove a single screw. Others have a guide rail screwed to the door (Photo 1).

[off-track roller](https://www.familyhandyman.com/bathroom/shower-installation/how-to-adjust-sliding-shower-doors/)

off-track roller is pretty common and it refers to sliding doors open and close on a track.

Comment: Makes sense, and your point "there is no hard and fast rule" taken. What troubles me is [this](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=970&tbm=bks&ei=70cOXcfGMq6IggfkvJqIDg&q=%22off+track+door%22): exactly 2 Google Books hits for "off track door", making it equally popular as ["off the track door"](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=970&tbm=bks&ei=hkkOXcnxGszM_AbG2LSwCQ&q=%22off+the+track+door%22&oq=%22off+the+track+door%22). Hard to fathom no writer has ever needed to describe such a scene as:"Peering through the off-track door, she spied a red dress hanging in the closet."

Comment: Hits are irrelevant **in this case**. The reason you are not finding more is because it is not a "type of door". It's a description of what happens to a door. English allows "an off-track door" to be created to describe a door that slipped off the rails on which it slides. This happens quite frequently with sliding closet doors or  sliding doors that give onto decks. Try googling: sliding doors + off track or come off track. If you were **suing the door manufacturer**, it would i indeed be: "the off-track door caused me many problems"

Comment: Furthermore, it is the door's rollers that come off track: see this for that:https://www.familyhandyman.com/bathroom/shower-installation/how-to-adjust-sliding-shower-doors/